# cant send date or null to datetime sql from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have an application that has two textboxes that the user can choose to enter a date. If there is no date, then I want to send null to sql. I have this:

My code to parse the `DateTime` values is as follows:

```
    if (ScheduledTextBox.Text == "") //Schedule Date
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduledDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduledDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
            DateTime.Parse(ScheduledTextBox.Text);
    }

    if (SourceDTTextbox.Text == "") //Source Date
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
            DateTime.Parse(SourceDTTextbox.Text);
    }
```

This returns an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

In my database, `ScheduledDT` is of type `(datetime, null)`.

This also happens when I enter what I would think to be a valid `DateTime`, such as

```
   2014-09-25 13:59:29
```

Stack trace:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.dll
    System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime. --->         System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType,   Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace - I strongly suspect it's not in the code you've shown.

Comment: Jon said `stack trace` as in the entire error message and the line numbers associated.

Comment: Why do you set the parameter equal to `DBNull.Value` regardless of whether the textbox is empty, but in different ways?

Comment: I don't see any code that turns the text of ScheduledTextBox.Text into a DateTime.  Where should that be?

Comment: Mathew that was a mistake in formatting, got confused..

Comment: The error message says that part of the SQL client code tried to convert a String to a DateTime.  After the DateTime.Parse call, the result is a DateTime.  Are any of the other time variables represented as strings?  If you enter valid dates in the two text boxes, does the program work?

Comment: No..I think it may have something to do with the time having AM or PM in it, so I'm looking for a way to convert the time I enter into UTC...

Comment: When you step through the code, are the values correctly populated in `ScheduledTextBox.Text` and `SourceDTTextbox.Text`?

Comment: I have call current UTC time for the textboxes which would be something like 2014-09-25 20:35:31. If this is in both or even 1 of the text boxes I get the error, also, if they are empty and I try to send null, it still gives the same error...

Comment: Show us the code that converts the textbox values to UTC time.

Comment: I used this just to see if it would work and I get the same error:    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduledDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.UtcNow;

Comment: Sorry guys I screwed up, had a bigint value set to datetime and just now saw it...thats what was throwing the error..4 hours wasted on an oversight...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my computer to test this, but it looks like your problem is with this line:

```
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduledDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
        DateTime.Parse(ScheduledTextBox.Text);
```

It should look something more like this:

```
DateTime myObject = DateTime.Parse(ScheduledTextBox.Text);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduledDT", myObject);
```

It looks like you're passing in the object type and not the actual object.

EDIT:
You could also use Parameters.Add instead of Parameters.AddWithValue...

```
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduledDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
        DateTime.Parse(ScheduledTextBox.Text);
```